# Suitable method for background processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm totally new to multi-process programming in Python 3 and I'm trying to find what's the best approach for my problem.
I have a main function with the following structure:

- init stage
- `while` loop with data gathering for T time
- processing gathered data in the quickest way to shorten the time where data is not gathered
- back to gathering

My idea is to put the data gathering to a separate process which could also run while the previously gathered data is being processed. This way the time window when no data is gathered could be as short as moving the data from the gathering process to the analyzer.

I searched Google on how to do this and how to share data between the gathering process, how to signal the process that I need data and how to get the collected data but there are a lot of ways I found (queue, manager, pipe, events) and I don't know what would be the best for this algorithm.
Where should I start looking? `multiprocess.Event()` looks promising for the signalling between the main and the background process, but I also want to get data (structured into a `dict`).

What do you recommend?

Comment: I'd use a queue (kafka or similar). It can enable two-way communication between gatherers and processors.

Comment: Queue would be best as suggested by @SergioTulentsev. Like producer-consumer pattern. You can either use Kafka/MQTT as suggested above or use Python's internal multi-process queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you could do it using a `multiprocessing.Queue` that your "data gatherer" could write to from a sub-process and from which your main process would read from to submit tasks to a `multiprocessing.Pool` instance. In the demo below, I am using the [`Pool.imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=imap) method, which conveniently allows me to use a generator function to specify the *iterable* representing the tasks to be submitted, which allows me to submit these tasks "lazily" as they become available and process the return values as the tasks complete.

For demo purposes, the "data" gathered are just integers taking .1 seconds each to gather and the processing consists of just squaring these integers taking approximately .25 seconds each to compute.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

QUARTER_SECOND_ITERATIONS = 5_000_000

def quarter_second():
    """ Burn up .25 seconds of CPU approximately on my desktop """
    sum = 0
    for _ in range(QUARTER_SECOND_ITERATIONS):
        sum += 1
    return sum


EOD = None # "end of data" indicator

def data_gatherer_worker(output_queue):
    """
    This runs in another process and "gathers" data.
    For demo purposes, we just generate some integers.
    """
    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(.1) # simulate taking .1 seconds to do this
        output_queue.put(i)
    output_queue.put(EOD) # end of data indicator


def data_gatherer():
    """ Generator function to get next input data. """
    output_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=data_gatherer_worker, args=(output_queue,))
    p.start()
    while True:
        data = output_queue.get()
        if data is EOD:
            # No more data
            break
        yield data
    p.join() # wait for process to complete


def init():
    """ Perform initialization phase. """
    ...

def process(data):
    """
    This runs in another process and processes the data.
    For demo purposes, we just square the passed integer and return the data and result.
    """
    # simulate .25 seconds of processing:
    quarter_second()
    return data, data ** 2


def main():
    """ Main logic """
    init()
    n_processors = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    # leave one processor free for data gathering
    with multiprocessing.Pool(n_processors - 1) as pool:
        # Submit new tasks as data becomes available
        # and get results as tasks complete:
        for result in pool.imap(process, data_gatherer()):
            # unpack:
            data, data_squared = result
            print(f'{data} ** 2 = {data_squared}')

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time.time()
    main()
    print('Total time:', time.time() - t)
```

Prints:

```
0 ** 2 = 0
1 ** 2 = 1
2 ** 2 = 4
3 ** 2 = 9
4 ** 2 = 16
5 ** 2 = 25
6 ** 2 = 36
7 ** 2 = 49
8 ** 2 = 64
9 ** 2 = 81
10 ** 2 = 100
11 ** 2 = 121
12 ** 2 = 144
13 ** 2 = 169
14 ** 2 = 196
15 ** 2 = 225
16 ** 2 = 256
17 ** 2 = 289
18 ** 2 = 324
19 ** 2 = 361
Total time: 2.636831045150757
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful. What I don't really understand yet is the pool part in main. Is it automatically assigning the execution of process() to currently available cores?

Comment: Each piece of data gathered (an integer in this case) becomes a new task submitted to the processing pool and is enqueued on a queue of tasks waiting to be processed. The processes in the pool just read these tasks from the queue and execute them (performed by function `process`) and when a process is done executing the task it just goes back and looks to see if there is another task waiting to be executed. In this case we have N - 1 processes in the pool where N is the number of cores plus we have the main process that is doing the data gathering for a total of N processes. (more ...)

Comment: So if nothing else were running in the system, we could expect to see all N of these processes running *in parallel* on all N cores., except: (1) Usually there are other processes running on your computer contending for the processors and (2) Function `cpu_count()` returns the number of *logical* cores on machines that differentiate between physical and logical cores. For example, my desktop has 8 logical cores and 4 physical cores, so with 8 logical cores even if there were no other processes contending I would not expect to see an 8-fold performance increase for tasks that were pure CPU.

Comment: The short answer to your question is: Yes.

Comment: That's quite a long version of a yes, but now I get it. I think I'll be able to tailor it to my needs, thanks.